# How to include validations on excel export to access (VBA Code)

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, export

I would like to know, if possible, how to implement sort of validation when exporting my data from excel to a table/db in MS Access.

Here it's the code I'm using:

```
Const TARGET_DB = "ProductsDB.accdb"

Sub PushTableToAccess()
Dim cnn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim MyConn
Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset
Dim i As Long, j As Long
Dim Rw As Long

Sheets("bd").Activate
Rw = Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row

Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection
MyConn = ThisWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & TARGET_DB

With cnn
.Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
.Open MyConn
End With

Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset
rst.CursorLocation = adUseServer
rst.Open Source:="CLNTITPUB", ActiveConnection:=cnn, _
CursorType:=adOpenDynamic, LockType:=adLockOptimistic, _
Options:=adCmdTable

For i = 2 To Rw
rst.AddNew
For j = 1 To 19
rst(Cells(1, j).Value) = Cells(i, j).Value
Next j
rst.Update
Next i

rst.Close
cnn.Close
Set rst = Nothing
Set cnn = Nothing

End Sub
```

DB Table:

| id_cot | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Peter |
| 2 | John |

What i want to include in the VBA Code is a validation before exporting the data the will check if is there any row filled with a specific value in a column, eg:

In the first row of the table, column "id_cot" is filled with "1". I want the code to prompt a "click box" to ask the user whether he wants to continue or not because there is already an "id_cot" with the same number.

Thanks

Comment: You want to check if value is already in Access? Open recordset filtered with that criteria and then check if recordset is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Hy,

You can try the code bellow, first, lets add a variable storing the value of the id_Cot value, then we search for it in the database and once it is found we ask the user to continue.

```
Dim strId_CotValue As String

For i = 2 To Rw
    
    For j = 1 To 19
    
    'Get the value of your ID.
    strId_CotValue = Cells(i, j).Value
    
        If IsIdUnique(strId_CotValue) = True Then
            If vbYes = MsgBox("Id already exists, continue ?", vbYesNo) Then
                rst.AddNew
                rst(Cells(1, j).Value) = Cells(i, j).Value
                rst.Update
            End If
        End If
        
    Next j
    
Next i
```

You can use this function to check if the id is unique, it will return true or false based on the given parameter. Don't forget to change the name of the table and variables. :

```
Public Function IsIdUnique(ByVal strIdValue As String) As Boolean

Dim blnIsIdUnique As Boolean
    '
blnIsIdUnique = Nz(DLookup("Id", "tblTest", "Id = " & CLng(strIdValue)), False)
    '
IsIdUnique = blnIsIdUnique
    
End Function
```

Is it this what you where after ?